# How can i dump /tmp/files in CentOS to Dropbox using crontab?

Tags: centos, cron, backup, dropbox

How can i dump files from my CentOS box to Dropbox account? As regular nightly backup task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0 1 * * * cp -a /tmp/files ~username/Dropbox/tmp_backups_$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Breakdown: Every day at one am make an archive copy of /tmp/files into a folder with the date as part of the name in 'username's dropbox.

Comment: I fail to see how it makes it to dropbox.com.  Is it assumed that client/daemon is running and will sync ~user/Dropbox automagically?

Comment: @alex: Yes. Once the daemon is installed and the user account configured, any file placed or edited inside the Dropbox folder will trigger a re-sync.